# ¿Porque una aplicación falla en la web mientras en localhost corre perfecta?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Buen dia, tengo una aplicación que funciona perfecto en el host local pero al subirla a host en la web se afecta el inicio de sesión. Aparece la siguiente advertencia:

> Advertencia : No se puede modificar la información del encabezado: los
>   encabezados ya enviados por (salida iniciada en
>   /storage/ssd1/181/5062181/public_html/index.php:1) en
>   /storage/ssd1/181/5062181/public_html/index.php en la línea 21

Elcódigo a que hace referencia es el siguiente (Está inmerso e un formulario):

```
<?php
  //session_start();
  if(isset($_SESSION['u_usuario']))
  {
    echo "Sesión exitosa\n BIENVENIDO";
  }
  else
  {
    header("Location: index.html");
  }

  ?>
```

Como dije funciona bien en localhost

Comment: Puede ser que la configuración del apache del servidor sea distinta a la que tienes en tu localhost.

Comment: Gracias Juan Manuel. ¿Como hago para establecer que la configuración sea igual en ambos servidores apache?

Comment: @LuisFernandoGonzalezBermude podrías subir el error completo?

Comment: Bienvenido Luis, te recomiendo leer [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea de calidad y sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: <?php
  //session_start();
  if(isset($_SESSION['u_usuario']))
  {
    echo "Sesión exitosa\n BIENVENIDO";
  }
  else
  {
    header("Location: index.html");
  }
  
  ?>

Comment: Advertencia : No se puede modificar la información del encabezado: los encabezados ya enviados por (salida iniciada en /storage/ssd1/181/5062181/public_html/index.php:1) en /storage/ssd1/181/5062181/public_html/index.php en la línea 21

Comment: Esta es la versión del software en localhost:
        Apache Web Server Version 2.4.25
        PHP Script Language Version 5.6.30 & 7.1.1
        MySQL Database Version 5.7.17
        phpMyAdmin Database Manager Version 4.6.6

    ChangeLog

Answer (score 0):

Corrige tu archivo de conexion.php, cuando ejecutamos una pagina localmente siempre usamos a "localhost" como nombre del servidor. Pero cuando deseamos subirlo a internet debemos modificar esto por el url del servidor donde tienes alojado tu base de datos. EJ: "http://servidor.com"

Tambien debes asegurarte que el nombre y contraseña de la base de datos sea la misma que tienes definido en tu conexion.

Comment: Gracias Raul. Todo lo que sugieres está bien establecido. El aplicativo se conecta correctamente a phpMyAdmin en el servidor. El código que no opera es el que dá la seguridad de inicio de sesión mediante session start(). Funciona a la perfección en localhost pero no así en el servidor web remoto. Me inclino a creer que el problema radica en la configuración del servidor Apache, como comento antes #JuanMa